# Run out rules in cricket if one player doesn't run

Tags: rules, cricket, officiating

Suppose A plays the ball and doesn't run out of his crease, but B runs and reaches A's crease and then the ball hits the stumps at B's crease.

Who is considered out or can either one sacrifice his wicket?

Answer (score 7):

1. If Player A - Does not leave the crease, Player B is out.
2. If both are out of the crease, the player **closest to the opposite crease** is considered Not-Out or vice-versa and NOT the player **arriving at crease first**.
   Example: Player A,B are out of the crease. Ball hits at B's crease, Player A is closest to the opposite crease; Player B is considered out.

Run Outs come under **[Law 38 - Cricket](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/)**

Answer (score 4):

If player A doesn't leave his ground (crease), then Player B is out. If both player has left the crease, then any player arriving at any crease earlier than other player is safe..

Answer (score 3):

If A player doesn't run then the player **B (which reach at A's crease) declared as out** in your case **because** player A doesn't left his crease. But if the ball hits the stumps at A's crease then no one considered as out.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the Batsmen have crossed in running, he who runs for the wick- et which is put down shall be out; if they have not crossed, he who has left the wicket which is put down shall be out. If a Batsman remains in his ground or returns to his ground and the other Batsman joins him there, the latter shall be out if his wicket is put down.

http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/ABOUT_CRICKET/LAWS/1980_CODE/LAW_38_RUN_OUT.html

Comment: -1 for referring to a massively out of date versions of the Laws. In the current Laws, you want [Law 29](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-29-batsman-out-of-his-ground/) which has important differences from what you have quoted.